# Repository does not have a release file error appears constantly

Tags: wine, 18.04

I tried installing WINE via the terminal but I was unable to install it. Since then I am constantly getting this error.

[image: terminal screenshot - winehq repository does not have a release file]

What should I do?

Comment: It's easier to read & answer when you copy text & have it as question instead of a picture.  I wanted to copy the https://... text and copy it into a browser, to check Bionic (18.04) is supported. If you do it, I'm sure when you get to the *dists* (supported releases) folder and find no bionic there, so 18.04 isn't supported (*at least not yet*)  I can't check for you, as I can't copy text from a picture/photo

Comment: WineHQ doesn't have a Bionic 18.04 package yet.  They're aware they're missing one, but don't have an ETA on a package yet.  (The possible duplicate explains more about what not having a release file means)

Answer (score 0):

I set my line in /etc/apt/sources.list

```
andrew@big-red-wired:~$ grep wine /etc/apt/sources.list
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ artful main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
andrew@big-red-wired:~$
```

Things work just fine.

HTH,
Andrew.